# ggplot2: faceted bar chart using proportions from multiple dummy vars, how to restructure data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet

I'm looking for a data visualization for multiple dummy variables faceted by gender. Because my sample size has way more women than men, I'd like to use proportions instead of counts, and I only want the proportion of successes (1). I don't wants bars for both 0 and 1.

I have a sense that I'll need to transform/restructure my data, but I'm not sure how. I know that `y = ..prop.., group = 1` will come into play, and that I'll probably have to use faceting, but I haven't come across any questions similar to what I'm trying to do.

My actual data set has 9 different forms of transport, not the 3 included here. I'm imagining a plot with three rows of bar plots, three variables per row. The y-axis is percentages and the X has a transport type, and above that, "Men" and "Women" with the percent of people who have 1 for that variable represented by the bar above. So six bars total per row, for three variables per row, and three rows total.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hWTPaVpjIZlHy6gFBXkagksqthYOlSVI/view?usp=sharing)'s a link to a very quick and rough sketch of what I'm looking for (but bear in mind the actual datasets has 9 variables, not the 3 pictured here).  Honestly though, I'm not super picky about the specifics so long as its a visualization that captures how men and women utilize transport differently.

```
#data
dfTrans <- data.frame(
  "transBus" = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
  "transCar" = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
  "transTaxi" = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
  "gender" = c("Man", "Woman", "Woman", "Woman", "Woman", "Man")
)

#This is the closest I've been able to come, which is not that close
ggplot(data = dfTrans) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = transBus, y = ..prop.., group = 1), stat = "count") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  facet_grid(. ~ gender)
```

Comment: Please upload your figure anyway, someone else can edit the question

Comment: @RichardTelford I added a link, thank you!

Comment: Gotta have CL53 to attempt to construct a MWE, which, honestly, is your responsibility It's an order of magnitude harder to answer this type of question in the abstract.

Answer (score 1):

Try gathering the data and the faceting by transport mode

```
dfTrans %>% 
  gather(key = mode, value = value, -gender) %>%
  mutate(value = factor(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = gender, fill = value)) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_fill()) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  facet_wrap(~mode)
```

[image]

**Update**

To just show the blue part you need to summarise the data before hand

```
dfTrans %>% 
  gather(key = mode, value = value, -gender) %>%
  group_by(mode, gender) %>% 
  summarise(prop = mean(value) ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = gender, y = prop)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  facet_wrap(~mode)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is so helpful! It worked perfectly with my full dataset. Do you have any idea for how to display only value = 1 (only the blue part of the bar)?

Comment: Re: your update - when I use that code I get ``Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `mode`.
* Plot is missing `mode`
* Layer 1 is missing `mode```

Comment: Code works when I copy-paste it. `mode` is made by `gather`. If you run the code until just after he summarise function, what do you get?

Comment: ``dfTrans %>% 
  gather(key = mode, value = value, -gender) %>%
  group_by(mode, gender) %>% 
  summarise(prop = mean(value) )`` returns 0.1584473 if I run it for my full dataset. For the sample data I used in my question, it returns 0.5.

Comment: I don't understand why it is not working for you. You should get a tibble with columns mode, gender and prop. Maybe restart R and load only tidyverse package